# Consecutive subset product

Tags: subset

I got this as an interview question and was thinking on how to solve it.
Lets say a number is an array ={7,6,3} and its consequtive substring ares {7},{6},{3},{7,6},{6,3},{7,6,3}({7,3} is not valid) check if product of any two subsets are equal).

so {6,2,3} fails as {6}={2*3}
can anyone give me a nudge in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If there are `n` numbers in the array. So there are `n * (n - 1) / 2` consequtive subsets. You can pre-process thess subsets' product, and insert into a `map`. Then enum the subsets to find if the product have more than twice in the `map`. Then you can solve this question.